# Transfer ownership from one user to another not working in Unity / Photon

Tags: unity, photon

I'm having trouble transfering ownership from one user to another in Unity Photon.  Basically one user who owns the object picks it up (enters `isMine`), then the other user touches the same object as well (enters `else` statement).

At this point the other user requests ownership, however `onOwnershiprequest` method is never called on the owner's side. The `else` statement is reached by the requesting owner and `photonView.RequestOwnership()` is called but this doesn't trigger `onOwnershiprequest` on the owner's side.

The following methods are included in the same `PickUpObject` script:

```
public void GrabCue()
{
    if (photonView.IsMine)
    {
        if (!isHeld && isBeingTouched)
        {
            // Current user grabs the object
            GrabObject();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!isHeld && isBeingTouched && ownerHoldsObject && bottleIsFull)
        {
            photonView.RequestOwnership();
            GrabObject();
        }
    }
}
```

In the same script but this is never called for the owner of the object:

```
public void OnOwnershipRequest(PhotonView targetView, Player requestingPlayer)
{
    Debug.Log("test");
}
```

Comment: On the PhotonView, what is the option for OwnershipTransfer?

Comment: I chose "Request" instead of "Fixed" or "Takeover"

Comment: Just to be sure, you have the interface IPunOwnershipCallbacks added?